Recover deleted LVM Thinpool
I have erroneously deleted a LVM Thinpool by deleting a VM in Proxmox. I need to recover the data from this Thinpool and I'm struggling on getting in up again.
LVS tells me:
LV                                         VG           Attr       LSize    Pool        Origin                                     Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
SAS_ARRAY_0                                SAS_ARRAY_0  twi---tz--   <3.61t
[SAS_ARRAY_0_tdata]                        SAS_ARRAY_0  Twi-------   <3.61t
[SAS_ARRAY_0_tmeta]                        SAS_ARRAY_0  ewi-------  <15.88g
[lvol0_pmspare]                            SAS_ARRAY_0  ewi-------  <15.88g
So something seems to be still there...
Any advice on how to continue from here?
Thanks!
